# Fixed positioned mobile menu not vertically scrollable

Tags: css

Here's my right mobile menu CSS:

```
.mobile_header_menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 280px;
    background: #fff;
    right: -280px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

When hamburger icon is clicked, some JS changes the right value to 0, which makes the menu coming from outside the screen (right side).

Problem: if the menu is taller than the screen it can't be scrolled. By using fixed instead of absolute I can scroll, but now the menu is always visible on the right with an horizontal scrollbar.

How to have the menu scrollable without being always visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to `.mobile_header_menu`